# Okay, I know the risks. ( Amateur Rocket.)

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, rocket-science, home-experiment, applied-physics

I am currently attending a school for electrical science. A small group of students and our instructor are attempting group project to build a liquid fuel rocket. (I know it is a bit out of the scope of our field of study.)
We have encountered a few issues when attempting to calculate the thrust of the rocket. (None of us have ANY prior experience with fluid/thermo dynamics.) The formula we found is
$$T=\dot m V_e+(p_e−p_a)A_e. $$

As I understand the formula, this reads "thrust = the amount of mass flowing multiplied by the speed of the exhaust, plus the difference in pressures multiplied by the area of the exhaust."

There are multiple questions. The first one is: how does one solve for the $V_e$ in this formula? The second is, does the simple mass flow equation $\dot m =rVA$ work? And if so, once again, how does one solve for velocity?

If it has not been made abundantly clear, this type of calculation is far beyond my current level of comfort. But I find it all quite fascinating.

Comment: Where are you running into trouble?  The phrasing of your question suggests an algebra question rather than a physics question.  In the later equation, you solve for velocity by dividing.  In the former, you subtract first and then divide.  Is there a physics question behind those two questions which I am just not seeing?

Comment: @CortAmmon Sorry, it may be just a question of the mathematics behind it. I am unable to understand how one solves for mass flow rate when velocity and thrust are both unknown. So I suppose I was asking how they relate practically so that I wrap my head around how to go about finding the values.

Comment: Solution: $V _e={T-(p_e-p_a)A_e\over \dot m}$ Be careful, when rocket motors are not correctly designed the often tend to turn into many rapidly moving fragments of so much $\mathbf{\text{remorseless}}$ metal.

Comment: If I could edit @AlbertusMagnus's comment, I'd bold the word "remorseless."  That was a great choice of word.

Comment: Question titles should contain the question, or some.manner of the question, which the body further clarifies.

Comment: Downvoted for the title, without meaning to deny that there are other good reasons to downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V_e$ is a property of the chosen propellant. In particular its   [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse). For example the liquid-hydrogen liquid oxygen combination has a specific impulse of 450 seconds.  This means that  a thrust of 450 pounds weight is produced  when the fuel is being burned at a rate of one pound mass per second.

Incidently I think  your thrust equation should be be
$$
T= \dot m  v_{e} \approx  A(p_{chamber}- p_{outside})
$$
i.e there is an approximately-equal sign and not a
sum of the two terms.

Comment: Very cool, when I was a kid I thought Werner Von Braun was the bee's knees!

Comment: Also worth noting that using the ISP of your propellant is idealized.  Practical issues with construction can result in a less efficient use of fuel, and thus the ISP of your system can be lower.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. That is interestingly the exact propellant that we are using.

Comment: I believe that I am still doing this math improperly I am getting a thrust of nearly 13 million Newtons.